# Use Beautiful Soup to unify #text after a tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm using Beautiful Soup to put in a excel table some infos from a website.
[image]

The bold titles are shown in the head columns while the text after the colon appear in the rows.

What I'm doing is finding the  text and searching for next_sibling -->

```
  book_year = sibling.pre.find('b',text='Anno:').next_sibling.get_text().strip()
```

The problem is that in some cases the text after colon, is split in different #text part. So if I use the next_sibling, it'll get only a partial info.

[image]

As you can see in the inspector, the content of **Titoli originali:** will only be *"da"* if I use next_sibling.

Is there a way to unify all those #text parts? How would you approach this problem?
Thank you

**UPDATES:**

This is the website I'm scraping from --> http://www.letteraturenordiche.it/danimarca.htm

It's giving me a hard time cause it has an incoherent structure and no use of classes.

One thing I did is to remove from the `<pre>` content all of the  tags, `<font>` tags and `<span>` tags, to leave only the `<b>` ones and take the text after that.

Comment: Can you show the relevant HTML source text?

Comment: @ggorlen i've updated the question with more infos about the websites. Tell me if you need more content or if i misunderstood the request

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. So what data/expected output are you trying to get ultimately?

Comment: @ggorlen I'm trying to fill an excel with "title, year, author, publisher, pages, notes, original title" as columns and as rows, all the books listed. Right now, the structure is fine, i'm getting all the books ecc. But the original title (Titolo originale: / Titoli originali:) is what's giving me more problem bc of the structure in the html. I've deleted all the <i> and <font> tags but now the next_sibling in some cases gives me only the first part of the split #text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parsing this document isn't pretty. Probable the document is hand-written in Word and then exported to HTML:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "http://www.letteraturenordiche.it/danimarca.htm"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "html.parser")

# preprocess the document:

# remove all whitespaces:
for w in soup.find_all(text=True):
    if not w.strip():
        w.extract()

# unwrap not necessary tags:
for t in soup.select("i, font, span"):
    t.unwrap()

# merge NavigableStrings together:
soup.smooth()

data = []
for t in soup.select("table"):
    title = t.p.get_text(separator=" ", strip=True)
    year = (
        t.select_one('b:-soup-contains("Anno:")')
        .find_next_sibling(text=True)
        .strip()
    )
    author = (
        t.find_previous("hr", attrs={"size": "6"})
        .find_previous("p")
        .get_text(strip=True)
    )
    editor = (
        t.select_one('b:-soup-contains("Editore:")')
        .find_next_sibling(text=True)
        .strip()
    )
    pages = (
        t.select_one('b:-soup-contains("Pagine:")')
        .find_next_sibling(text=True)
        .strip()
    )
    notes = (
        t.select_one('b:-soup-contains("Note:", "Comprende")')
        .find_next_sibling(text=True)
        .strip()
    )
    original_title = t.select_one(
        'b:-soup-contains("Titolo Original", "Titolo original", "Titoli originali")'
    )

    if not original_title:
        original_title = t.find(lambda t: t.text.strip() == ":")

    if not original_title:
        original_title = ""
    else:
        original_title = original_title.find_next_sibling(text=True).strip()

    data.append((title, year, author, editor, pages, notes, original_title))

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data,
    columns=[
        "title",
        "year",
        "author",
        "editor",
        "pages",
        "notes",
        "original_title",
    ],
)
df["title"] = df["title"].str.replace(r"\r?\n", " ", regex=True)
df["author"] = df["author"].str.replace(r"\r?\n", " ", regex=True)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Creates the dataframe and saves it as `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]